# Variable interest rate. How can I get the rate to switch when interest it fits the condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, recursion

I am trying to get the interest rate to automatically switch when the total compound reaches in its range.
I enter, principal, a monthly total and term.
It is only calculating the compound interest for the first year. I want to be able for it to send that amount back into the function for it to calculate all over again until the term ends.

```
def IntEarned(p, m, t):
    principal = p
    monthly_deposit = m
    invested = t


        currentamount = principal + (monthly_deposit * 12)

    def currentTest():

        if currentamount < 100000:
            interest =  (0.05 / 100)
            return interest
        elif currentamount < 200000:
            interest =  (0.10 / 100)
            return interest
        elif currentamount < 250000:
            interest =  (0.15 / 100)
            return interest
        elif currentamount < 500000:
            interest = (0.25 / 100)
            return interest
        elif currentamount < 1000000:
            interest = (0.40 / 100)
            return interest
        elif currentamount < 2000000:
            interest =  (0.55 / 100)
            return interest
        elif currentamount < 5000000:
            interest =  (0.60 / 100)
            return interest
        elif currentamount >= 5000000:
            interest =  (0.70 / 100)
            return interest



    while (invested > 0):
        currentamount = currentamount + (currentamount * currentTest())
        invested = invested - 1
        return currentamount
```

**So I ran it with IntEarned(10000, 10, 1000)) and I got 10125.06, which is right for the first year.**

Comment: It works in mine. It' just that it is only giving me the first total.

Comment: I'm assuming `invested` is really your term?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def calc_accrual(p, m, t, i):
    t -= 1
    p = p + (m * 12)

    if p < 100000:
        i += p * 0.0005
        p *= 1.0005
    elif p < 200000:
        i += p * 0.0010
        p *= 1.0010
    elif p < 250000:
        i += p * 0.0015
        p *= 1.0015
    elif p < 500000:
        i += p * 0.0025
        p *= 1.0025
    elif p < 1000000:
        i += p * 0.0040
        p *= 1.0040
    elif p < 2000000:
        i += p * 0.0055
        p *= 1.0055
    elif p < 5000000:
        i += p * 0.0060
        p *= 1.0060
    else:
        i += p * 0.0070
        p *= 1.0070

    if t > 0:
        return calc_accrual(p, m, t, i)
    else:
        return p, i
```

**Tests**:

```
>>> calc_accrual(10000, 10, 1, 0)
>>> (10125.06, 5.0600000000000005)
>>> calc_accrual(10000, 10, 1000, 0)
>>> (204357.25738374083, 74357.25738374837)
```

Comment: How would you sum up the total interest?

Comment: @NicoleFoster Edited the post that also returns the interest accrued :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your ranges to an interest rate with a search like:

```
def interest_per_value(value):
    interest_table = (
        (100000, 0.05),
        (200000, 0.10),
        (250000, 0.15),
        (500000, 0.25),
        (1000000, 0.40),
        (2000000, 0.55),
        (5000000, 0.60),
    )
    for test_value, rate in interest_table:
        if value < test_value:
            return rate / 100
        return 0.70 / 100
```